Maximum function recursive property
In an old book by Richard Bellman, I found a proof of the initial Bellman equation:
$$
f_n(x)=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[g_N(x_N)+f_{N-1}(x-x_N)\right]
$$
where $x_i\ge 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=x$. After an intuitive derivation of this equation, he used the following $\max$ function property to prove this equation by induction:
$$
\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N=x \land x_i\ge 0}=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{N-1}=x-x_N \land x_i\ge 0}\right]
$$
The proof proceeds as follows:
$$
f_N(x)=\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N=x \land x_i\ge 0}\left[g_N(x_N)+g_{N-1}(x_{N-1})+\cdots+g_1(x_1)\right]=
$$.
$$
=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{N-1}=x-x_N \land x_i\ge 0}\left[g_N(x_N)+g_{N-1}(x_{N-1})+\cdots+g_1(x_1)\right]\right]=
$$
$$
=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[g_N(x_N)+\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{N-1}=x-x_N \land x_i\ge 0}\left[g_{N-1}(x_{N-1})+\cdots+g_1(x_1)\right]\right]=
$$
$$
=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[g_N(x_N)+f_{N-1}(x-x_N)\right]
$$
How can we understand this $\max$ function property? Is it an operational equation? How can I prove it?

Here is my try basing on RobPratt comment.
I assume that the left-hand side of the equation is greater than the right-hand side
$$
\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N=x \land x_i\ge 0}>\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{N-1}=x-x_N \land x_i\ge 0}\right]
$$
and let $x^=(x_1^,x_2^,\ldots,x_N^)$ be the solution that maximizes the left-hand side of the equation. Then, we also have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}x_i^*=x-x_N^*
$$
$$
\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N=x \land x_i\ge 0}=f(x^*)
$$
where $f(x^*)$ is the value of the function for the solution $x^*$.
Since $x^*$ maximizes the function given that $x_N^*$ is fixed, we must have
$$
\max_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{N-1}=x-x_N \land x_i\ge 0}=g(x_N^*)
$$
where $g(x_N^*)$ is the value of the inner $\max$ function (I have trouble naming this). Then it holds that
$$
f(x^*)=\max_{0\le x_N\le x}\left[g(x_N)\right]
$$
which leads to a contradiction
$$
f(x^*) > f(x^*)
$$
I admit that I feel the proof somewhat, but I still see some magical notations here. Is it even correct? I understand that the inequality needs to be proven in the other direction as well.

Not sure this property has a name, but you could call it conditioning on the value of $x_N$.  You can prove the equality by contradiction.  Assume one side is larger and then show that the other side is not really maximized because you can increase the value.
